# file extention filtering does not work in procmail

Tags: fedora, procmail

procmail will not download just .xls, .doc and .docx extentions. every condition i have found either downloads everything or nothing. i am using fedora 14

conditions i have tried that dont download anything are:

```
*^[ ]* name:.*\.(xls|doc|docx)  
*^      name.*\.(xls|doc|docx)  
* ?? name:.*\.(xls|doc|docx)  
* filename:.\.(xls|doc|docx)
```

... and ever other combination of those.

EDIT:
i have tried all of these as well.

```
* name=.*\.(xls|doc|docx)   
* ^.*name=.*.(xls|doc|docx)  
* ^.*name.*\.(xls|doc|docx)  
*^Content-.*attachment.*name=.*\.(xls|doc|docx)
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Procmail doesn't "download" anything.  You apparently already solved this to your satisfaction, but the terminology should be cleaned up, and I'm still not sure I understand the question.  If you have a better understanding now, please clarify what you wanted to accomplish so that others who have the same needs can benefit from this discussion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trapping 'multipart' content types first *may* help, but my procmail is a little rusty:

```
:0
* ^Content-Type: multipart/
{
  :0 B
  * ^Content-.*attachment.*name=.*\.(doc|xls)
  {
```

This should catch any .doc, .docx, .xls or .xlsx attachments.

Comment: Yes Your code worked like a charm! its funny every single tutorial and artical i found code did not work at all. you saved me from a headache.